# Trying to select a single random row from DB using entity framework (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, select, random, stringbuilder

I need to grab just one row, and output its name and details properties to a sidebox on my page.

So far I have come up with this, which is not working and giving cast errors between the entity and the list of.

```
Public Shared Function GetOneRow() As String
    Dim db As New Model.Entities
    Dim rowCount As Integer = (From t In db.Table Select t).Count
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = New Random().Next(rowCount)
    Dim query = (From t In db.Table Select t Where t.id = randomNumber).FirstOrDefault
    Dim rowList As New List(Of Model.Table)
    rowList.Add(query)
    Dim htmlString As New StringBuilder
    htmlString.Append("<h1>" & rowList(0).name.ToString & "</h1>")
    htmlString.Append("<p>" & rowList(0).details.ToString & "</p>")
    Return htmlString.ToString
End Function
```

Have also tried:

```
Public Shared Function GetOneRow() As String
    Dim db As New Model.Entities
    Dim query = From t In db.Table Select t
    Dim count As Integer = query.Count
    Dim index As Integer = New Random().Next(count)
    Dim list As New List(Of Model.Table)
    list.AddRange((query.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault))
    Dim htmlstring As New StringBuilder
    htmlstring.Append("<h1>" & list(0).name.ToString & "</h1>")
    htmlstring.Append("<p>" & list(0).details.ToString & "</p>")
    Return htmlstring.ToString
End Function
```

The error here is: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Is there an easier way to just pick one random row from the table, and get its name and details properties into my stringbuilder?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: According to relational theory, rows aren't supposed to be "random"!  But your best bet is to use something row_number() (SQL Server) or ROWID (Oracle).

Comment: using entity framework / sql server. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

following code works for my in C#, sorry I'm not very good in VB

```
      //Note the (from and in and select) are case sensitive.
      var qry = from t in db.Table select t;

      int count = qry.Count();
      int index = new Random().Next(count);

      //Need to call OrderBy first for this to Skip to run properly.
      //return qry.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();

      return = qry.OrderBy(c => c.YourField).Skip(myIndex).FirstOrDefault();
```